# Confusion with algebraic manipulation of inductive step

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

This algebraic leap in the induction step confused me.

(k+1)!-1+(k+1)(k+1)!=(1+k+1)(k+1)!-1

Can somebody help me understand the algebra of this?

Comment: $a+b\cdot a=(1+b)\cdot a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $(k+1)!-1 +(k+1)(k+1)! = (k+1)! + (k+1)(k+1)! - 1 = (1+(k+1))(k+1)! - 1$. In the last equation you just have to pull out $(k+1)!$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!